# Why popover does not have an arrow on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, popover

I am displaying a popover on a button press. Popover points its arrow to the button pressed:

```
UIViewController * controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"popover view"];
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
controller.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = button.imageView;

[self presentViewController: controller
                   animated: YES
                 completion: nil];
```

This is how popover view controller is defined in a storyboard:
[image]

The problem is that on iPhone this popover is drawn fullscreen, while on iPad and Mac it is drawn with an arrow pointing to the button. I want it to have an arrow always.

I have seen that popovers on iPhone can have arrows, but cannot get it. What am I missing? Why iPhone popover is drawn fullscreen and without an arrow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement [adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:traitCollection:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiadaptivepresentationcontrollerdelegate/1618334-adaptivepresentationstyleforpres?language=objc) of `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` and return `UIModalPresentationNone` for `popoverPresentationController` `delegate`

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller
                                                               traitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection
{
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```